# Shorthand for checking if a string contains substrings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string `S` and strings `s_1, s_2, s_3, s_4`.

I want to do the following:

```
if s_1 not in S and s_2 not in S and s_3 not in S and s_4 not in s:
   code...
```

Is there a shorthand for this?

Something like

```
If s_1, s_2, s_3, s_4 not in S:
   code...
```

But this doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 2):

You can youse list comprehension (read more about it [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension):

```
lst = [s_1, s_2, s_3, s_4]
```

in case you want that all s_... are not in S, use:

```
all(x not in S for x in lst)
```

in case it is enough if one s_... is not in S, use:

```
any(x not in S for x in lst)
```

Comment: @khelwood, ohhh I wasn't aware of that, very nice thanks!